# Click event prevents mouseout from triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, removeclass

**FINAL EDIT:** I found a better solution and more simpler on this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vuKrf). A [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s4reu3kr/) of the working functionality.

EDIT: I found where the bug is coming from you can see an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8pksytqk/). When you click on lets say the About tab and hover over and out on contact the content should be hidden. But you go back to hover over About and out the content stays visible, which is not. How do I ensure the mouseout event is being triggered after clicked?

EDIT 2: So I noticed the unbind() method prevents that. When I remove it I can't seem to get the content area to stay active when clicked as the mouseout method overrides it.

I did some research on this but could not find a solution as to why on hover the removeclass does not work. I have encountered a bug with addClass() and removeClass() functions. The thing is I have those function firing on hover or mouseover/mouseout and on click so it gets a bit confusing. Here is a demo of what I'm working with: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2x63n4u/5/).

[Full screen](https://jsfiddle.net/n2x63n4u/5/embedded/result/) for better view.

My JavaScript can be kind of messy but ultimately the way this is suppose to work:

**1.** If you hover over a dot on the map the content on the left red box should reveal what's relevant to the location as well as a 'tooltip' of the location name. (this part works)

**2.** You mouse out it's suppose to go back to the list of locations and the tooltip disappears. Almost like a reset.

**3.** Now if you click on the dot, both the tooltip and the content on the left should remain active. Until you either click on the "Back to the list" link on the red box or hover over the other dots. (this also works)

The bug I encountered is if you click around the list panel and hover over a couple of the location dots after a certain while the hover state stays active when you hover over a couple of the locations (which is not suppose to happen). Everything is suppose to go back the list panel when you hover out of the location dot on the map.

```
    $('a.location').click(function (event) {
    var loc = this.id;
    if ($('div.panel').hasClass('list')) {
        $('div.' + loc).removeClass('current');
        $('.list').addClass('current');
    }
    $('.list').removeClass('current');
    $('div.panel.' + loc).addClass('current');
    event.preventDefault();
}); //click function
$('.back-list').click(function (e) {
    $('.panel').removeClass('current');
    $('.list').addClass('current');
    $('div.location-title.show').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    $('div.location-title.view').removeClass('view');
    e.preventDefault();
}); //back button


$('ul.locations li > a').hover(function () {
//show location hover
var dot = this.id;
$('div.location-title.' + dot).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');

}, function () {
    var dot = this.id;
    //hide location hover
    $('div.location-title.' + dot).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
}).click(function (event) {
    var dot = this.id;
    if (!$('div.location-title.' + dot).hasClass('hide')) {
        $('div.location-title.' + dot).addClass('view');
    } else {
        $('div.location-title.' + dot).removeClass('view');
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('.map__container > span').on({
mouseover: function () { //mouseover
    var loc = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.panel').siblings().removeClass('current'); //resets all classes that have current
    $('.list').removeClass('current');
    $('div.panel.' + loc).addClass('current');
    $('div.show').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    $('div.location-title.' + loc).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
    var asb = $('.location-title').siblings();
    $('div.location-title').siblings().removeClass('view');
},
mouseout: function () { //mouseout
    var loc = $(this).attr('class');
    $('div.' + loc).removeClass('current');
    $('div.location-title.' + loc).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    if (!$('div.' + loc).hasClass('current')) {
        $('.list').addClass('current');
    } else {
        $('.list').addClass('current');
    }
},
click: function () {
    $(this).off('mouseout');
    var loc = $(this).attr('class');
    $('div.location-title.show').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    $('div.location-title.' + loc).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
}
});
```

Also if you have better suggestions to clean up my JavaScript I'm all ears. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right, you might want to try with the event Mouseleave, and i would use to modularize the function toggleClass:

- [ToggleClass function Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)
- [Mouseleave explanation:](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

  ```
  mouseleave: function () { //mouseout
  var loc = $(this).attr('class');
  $('div.' + loc).removeClass('current');
  $('div.location-title.' + loc).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
     if (!$('div.' + loc).hasClass('current')) {
        $('.list').addClass('current');
     } else {
        $('.list').addClass('current');
  }
  },
  ```

I hope this **helps you**. Salutations!

Answer (score 0):

**FINAL EDIT:** I found a better solution and more simpler on this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vuKrf). A [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s4reu3kr/) of the working functionality.

My problem was in the code example above the `$(this).off('mouseout');` was removing the mouseout when clicked. So if you were to hover back to that dot on the map and mouseout the 'tooltip' would stay active, it won't disappear when you mouseout, which it should disappear. I couldn't find a way to bind it again so the toggleClass() was much better. I been pulling my hair on this!

```
 $('.map__container span').click(function(mapIcon){
                    mapIcon.preventDefault();
                    var icon = $(this).attr('class');  
                    var panel = $(this).attr('class');  

                    $('.panel').removeClass('clicked');
                    $('.location-title').removeClass('clicked');
                    $('.panel.' + panel).addClass('clicked');
                    $('.location-title.' + icon).addClass('clicked');
                });                
                //Show bubbles over dots on map
                $('.map__container span').hover(function(){
                    var hoverdot = $(this).attr('class');

                    $('.location-title.' + hoverdot).toggleClass('selected');
                });
                //Show bubbles on hover over anchor links
                $('a.location').hover(function(){
                    var hoverlink = this.id;

                    $('.location-title.' + hoverlink).toggleClass('selected');
                });
                //Anchor links show panels and bubbles
                $('a.location').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var panel = this.id;
                    var icon = this.id;

                    $('.panel').removeClass('clicked');
                    $('.location-title').removeClass('clicked');
                    $('.panel.' + panel).addClass('clicked');
                    $('.location-title.' + icon).addClass('clicked');                        
                });
                //back button
                $('.back-list').click(function(backButton) {
                     backButton.preventDefault();

                    $('.panel').removeClass('clicked');
                    $('.location-title').removeClass('clicked');
                    $('.list').addClass('clicked');                              
                });
```